# How can I ungroup these permanently grouped speakers on my Heos System

Tags: sound

I am using a Heos / Denon system.  I have speakers in each room with home theatre support in two rooms (Living and Lounge).  For some reason these two rooms are permanently grouped together.

I can group others and ungroup them.  A can even drag another room into this fixed group and remove that room.  I just cant separate the Lounge and Living.  This causes confusion sometimes when the wrong speaker starts emitting sound after its companion is switched off.

Normal drag out or pinch out has no effect on this set.  How can I ungroup them?

[image]

Comment: Not knowing the details of this, here's a guess: I think there's confusion between rooms, devices, zones. I think you've setup Living, spare, lounge as zones of the home theater amplifier and not as rooms. Maybe you can drag kitchen into Guest Speakers and group them and then ungroup them. Maybe ! Let us know what you find out. Also, there maybe some home theater multi room type of forums on the internet where you may have better luck. What app is it that you're using anyway ?

Comment: I updated the question.  Its Heos / Denon.  It was set up this way by the installer about 7 years ago.  We have always had confusion but things sort of worked most of the time.  I am trying to get Alexa to work.  It is working on all rooms except these two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally had an answer rom teh installer.  It may help others.

> **Lounge/Living HEOS:** These 2x zones are on the Denon AVR. There is only one HEOS streamer input, so you can only switch zones on/off and not ungroup. All other HEOS zones are fully matrixed with a HEOS streamer per zone.